# How to completely and fully configure WxWidgets' CMake install/build directories?

Tags: macos, cmake, build, gnu-make, wxwidgets

I am trying to integrate WxWidgets (3.1.5) into an existing CMake project's build chain (CMake 3.21.2) on macOS (10.15 [Catalina]) such that WxWidgets is fully subordinate to the main project's CMake settings/variables (and nothing leaves the project's directory [I am doing out of source builds]). I am making good process on getting *everything* in WxWidgets' CMake scripts controlled except that for some reason it still wants to keep putting libraries in `usr/local/lib` and making symlinks in `usr/local/bin`. I am not sure what variable I am missing in the WxWidgets CMake build scripts because everything should be routing to the locations I overrode.

Here's the relevant files and lines I changed.

CMakeLists.txt (WxWidgets Root, Lines 43 ~ 46 [Original Lines](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L43))

```
set(wxSOURCE_DIR "path/to/my/project/libs/wxWidgets_src")
set(wxBINARY_DIR "path/to/my/project/build/libs/wxWidgets")
set(wxOUTPUT_DIR "${wxBINARY_DIR}/wxWidgets")
```

I commented out the `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` block as well but that does not affect anything.

install.cmake (build/cmake/install.cmake, Lines 16 - 78 [Original Lines](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/build/cmake/install.cmake#L16))

```
wx_install(
        DIRECTORY "${wxSOURCE_DIR}/include/wx"
        DESTINATION "path/to/my/project/install/wxWidgets/include")
    if(MSVC)
        wx_install(
            DIRECTORY "${wxSOURCE_DIR}/include/msvc"
            DESTINATION "path/to/my/project/install/wxWidgets/include")
    endif()
else()
    wx_get_flavour(lib_flavour "-")
    wx_install(
        DIRECTORY "${wxSOURCE_DIR}/include/wx"
        DESTINATION "path/to/my/project/install/wxWidgets/include/wx-${wxMAJOR_VERSION}.${wxMINOR_VERSION}${lib_flavour}")
endif()

# setup header and wx-config
if(WIN32_MSVC_NAMING)
    wx_install(
        DIRECTORY "${wxSETUP_HEADER_PATH}"
        DESTINATION "path/to/my/project/install/wxWidgets/lib${wxPLATFORM_LIB_DIR}")
else()
    wx_install(
        DIRECTORY "${wxSETUP_HEADER_PATH}"
        DESTINATION "path/to/my/project/install/wxWidgets/lib/wx/include")

    wx_install(
        FILES "${wxOUTPUT_DIR}/wx/config/${wxBUILD_FILE_ID}"
        DESTINATION "path/to/my/project/install/wxWidgets/lib/wx/config"
        PERMISSIONS OWNER_EXECUTE OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ
                    GROUP_EXECUTE GROUP_READ
                    WORLD_EXECUTE WORLD_READ
        )

    install(DIRECTORY DESTINATION "path/to/my/project/install/wxWidgets/bin")
    # Disable symlinks
    # install(CODE "execute_process( \
    #     COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink \
    #     ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/wx/config/${wxBUILD_FILE_ID} \
    #     ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/wx-config \
    #     )"
    # )
endif()

# uninstall target
if(MSVC_IDE)
    set(UNINST_NAME UNINSTALL)
else()
    set(UNINST_NAME uninstall)
endif()

if(NOT TARGET ${UNINST_NAME})
    # these symlinks are not included in the install manifest
    set(WX_EXTRA_UNINSTALL_FILES)
    if(NOT WIN32_MSVC_NAMING)
        if(IPHONE)
            set(EXE_SUFFIX ".app")
        else()
            set(EXE_SUFFIX ${CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX})
        endif()

        set(WX_EXTRA_UNINSTALL_FILES
            "path/to/my/project/install/wxWidgets/bin/wx-config"
            "path/to/my/project/install/wxWidgets/bin/wxrc${EXE_SUFFIX}"
            )
```

Some of the edits seem to be over zealous for parts that don't affect MacOS builds but I just wanted to be sure.

The only other indication of some fishy directory work going on, that I could find, was in config.cmake ([Lines 140 ~ 150](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/build/cmake/config.cmake#L140)) with the usage of `wxBUILD_TOOLKIt` but this (set inside of toolkit.cmake) doesn't seem to do anything relating to installing files (it just sets it to [`osx-cocoa`, Lines 29 ~ 44](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/build/cmake/toolkit.cmake#L29)) and seems related to linking in libraries for the build process and nothing to do with installation.

I am not sure what else could be touching the `/usr/local` directories during install.  The ideal goal here is that WxWidgets is not a separately built dependency for my project to just bring in (i.e. don't just add some `.dll/.dylib` files and `.h` files and away you go) but rather a full sub-library that is built right from the source (as either a static lib or shared lib) and done locally right alongside the main project's own CMake build chain (i.e. where ever my project's build folder would reside or install targets would point to). I don't want to have anything leak outside of the project's directory (install commands are somewhat dangerous as they can put stuff deep in system directories) and running make commands on any 3rd party library is very risky because you never *really* know where stuff is going (i.e. what directories are changed/created, permissions needed, libraries being exposed globally, etc.).

P.S.

Just in case it matters, here's how I am linking it (yes, I know it's not `Modern CMake` compliant ... it's just for getting it integrated/working at the moment):

Source/Attribution Credits: [doxygen/overviews/cmake.md, Lines 114 ~ 126](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/docs/doxygen/overviews/cmake.md#using-a-sub-directory------------------cmake_subdir)

```
# WxWidgets
add_subdirectory("path/to/my/project/libs/wxWidgets_src")
target_link_libraries(MyExe PUBLIC wx::net wx::core wx::base)
```

Comment: Modifying `CMakeLists.txt` of the other project for configuration needs is normally the last approach one should use. If you want to control installation directory of `WxWidgets`, you could use [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) and pass appropriate `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` for it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I get what you're saying but one loses too much control with tools like `ExternalProject_Add`. I don't ever want a build system downloading a repository or executing arbitrary commands (major security risk) against malicious code (all code is malicious until proven otherwise). All projects should be totally isolated and self-contained (like in this case). Messing around with prefixes and command line arguments just leads to path/arg hell and a mess of indirection.  Plus we see what's going on under the hood (make sure the library's not touching stuff it doesn't need to).

Comment: If you bother about security, then you firstly need to decide what you trust and what you don't. If you trust CMake, then you could trust `ExternalProject_Add`, which is a **part** of the CMake. Otherwise you shouldn't use CMake at all. If you trust the code which builds `WxWidgets` (that it, its `CMakeLists.txt`), then you needn't to modify it and use "as is". Otherwise you need to **completely rewrite** its `CMakeLists.txt`. `ExternalProject_Add` builds projects in the environment where they are tested. Not many projects are ready for being included via `add_subdirectory`

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for reminding me, I forgot to add the doc link showing where they recommended using `add_subdirectory`. The `CMakeLists.txt` looks like it is fine (i.e. there are no missing paths involving installation). I do not see a reason that I would need to _completely_ rewrite the `CMakeLists.txt`/`.cmake` scripts. I just need to find out where they put all the paths for builds/installs and change just those pieces. Edit: I think I found the remaining places where it touches directories (I needed to rgrep harder). I will post the general solution, in case anyone else needs it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'd argue on this. `ExternalProject_Add` runs an arbitrary CMake code coming from 3rd party, which can do whatever it likes.

Comment: @david, why does it matter where the install goes? Also remember - the target machine could have an install of wxWidgets that is needed by other software and you don't want to overwrite that.

Comment: @Igor Why doesn't it matter? Why shouldn't it be allowed to be controlled? What if we want to statically link WxWidgets instead of using dynamic linking? What if we want to make sure our systems don't get polluted by throwing libs and exes every which way? Why do we assume the target machine _will_ have WxWidgets installed? These are all great questions that really should be open to let the people using the project decide how to handle them.

Comment: @David, `/usr/local/lib` is the de-facto preferred place to install all 3rd party software. `/usr/lib` is the place to install all system libraries by the default package manager. One more time - if you already have wxWidgets installed by the package manager in `/usr/lib`, you don't want to overwrite this. Especially on the client computer. You can decide to install it inside ~/wxWidgets and then use the linker, but there is no differences between `/usr/local/lib` and `~/wxWidgets`.

Comment: On top of that - you are the developer of the project and it is your responsibility to handle those cases. As I said - `/usr/local/lib` is the *nix way to install 3rd party libraries (here the meaning is - `not managed by the package manager`, not 3rd party libraries per se). You can even delete those libraries after the build if you want static linking (which is rarely needed under *nix) or use appropriate LD_CONFIG_PATH variable override.

Comment: @Igor I do not think we disagree. I want to do something very similar to what you noted of instead of having any/all `WxWidget` binaries be in `/usr/local/bin` they can be in a different directory (like `~/WxWidgets`, and linked accordingly). I am not sure what the philosophical opposition is to the approach of keeping everything clean, isolated, and self-contained to a project's directory (or even its distribution directory)? I found some archive/library/runtime destination settings in the `functions.cmake` that looked like they needed changing too. I will check `LD_CONFIG_PATH` too.

Comment: you still not answering the main question - what is the difference between `/usr/local/lib` and `~/wxWidgets`?

Comment: @Igor I did though... It keeps everything isolated, cleanly self-contained in the project's directory (even potentially, if dynamically linked, during distribution too) so that dev environments are clean (no version conflicts, directory digging, magic side effects) and users wouldn't need to install WxWidget (because that's terrible UX) or have conflicts/break anything that may use older versions. Globalized libraries/etc. is terrible because things can conflict and break other software (... it has happened to me).